# Can a single facebook app show different content on 2 or more tabs?

Tags: facebook, iframe-app

Is it possible to create a single facebook app (iframe) that can be used to have 2 or more different tabs on a business page? I have not been able to see how to do this and it seem wrong to me to have to have multiple appID's  and apps just for a second tab..

Comment: I was just abouts to ask the same and stumble across your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

You just need to install the app in different pages. I did my apps with the PHP SDK. You can show different options depending on:

- User like: `$like_status` (yes/no)
- Facebook page ID: `$page_id` (some pages load some content, some others don't)
- Language/locale: `$locale` (`en_UK`, `en_US`, `es_ES`, `es_LT`, `de_DE`, ...)
- Country: `$country`
- Page admin: `$page_admin`

More info:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
- https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I've already seen a lot of the "welcome tab" and custom iframe tab applications have multiple apps with the additional ones called "2nd tab", "3rd tab", etc.  So, I think each application can only add one tab to a page.